# Bitcoin and Litecoin wallets with push notification API?

Tags: wallet, client, api, litecoin

I am working on a project which includes btc and ltc transactions. I need Bitcoin and Litecoin wallets with APIs that could create Push notification on newly received transactions. With API I mean any kind of communication (Interface, REST API etc.). Can anybody show me the way or name the wallets? Wallet needs to be local not remote website with service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run bitcoind/litecoind with the -walletnotify flag, which runs a script when a transaction is received.  The script could then send a notification.

```
./bitcoind -walletnotify=<your script name> %s
```

The %s is replaced with the hash of the incoming transaction.

Answer (score 0):

blockchain.info offer an API and a notification thing.

Comment: I want local wallet. Not remote website.